# Can I specify an alternate port when importing a Data Protector Client

Tags: configuration, port, data-protector

I want to import a Windows Data Protector client that uses (legacy) port 5555 into a Cell Server running 11.02.
When I try it, I'm offered the certificate to accept, but the I get an `[12:1625] Import host failed.` error.

I suspect that it's due to the fact that recent installations default to using port 5565 instead.

So my question is:
Is there a way to specify the port to use when importing a client?
(I tried to add the port as ":portnr" to the host name, but that was not accepted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem from the client side (not from the server side):

I did "repair" on Windows for the existing installation.
At the end a command (`omnicc -secure_comm ...`) to register the client at the cell server was suggested (unsure why that was suggested).
When executing the suggested command as administrative user, success was reported, and the Cell Server knew the client with the correct software components installed.